# UTF-8 conversion

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, json, utf-8

I am grabbing a JSON array and storing it in an NSArray. However it includes JSON encoded UTF-8 strings, for example pass\u00e9 represents passé.  I need a way of converting all of these different types of strings into the actual character.  I have an entire NSArray to convert.  Or I can convert it when it is being displayed, which ever is easiest.

I found this chart http://tntluoma.com/sidebars/codes/

Is there a convenient method for this or a library I can download?

thanks,

BTW, there is no way I can find to change the server so I can only fix it on my end...

Comment: If you create `NSString` objects using the class method `+ (id)stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)bytes`, will it display correctly?

Comment: would you be able to provide an example?  I am not familiar with using a const char.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use an approach based on the [NSScanner](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html). The following code (not bug-proof) can gives you a way on how it can work:

```
NSString *source = [NSString stringWithString:@"Le pass\\u00e9 compos\\u00e9 a \\u00e9t\\u00e9 d\\u00e9compos\\u00e9."];
NSLog(@"source=%@", source);

NSMutableString *result = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:source];
[scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:nil];
while (![scanner isAtEnd]) {
    NSString *chunk;

    // Scan up to the Unicode marker
    [scanner scanUpToString:@"\\u" intoString:&chunk];
    // Append the chunk read
    [result appendString:chunk];

    // Skip the Unicode marker
    if ([scanner scanString:@"\\u" intoString:nil]) {

        // Read the Unicode value (assume they are hexa and four)
        unsigned int value;
        NSRange range = NSMakeRange([scanner scanLocation], 4);
        NSString *code = [source substringWithRange:range];
        [[NSScanner scannerWithString:code] scanHexInt:&value];
        unichar c = (unichar) value;

        // Append the character
        [result appendFormat:@"%C", c];

        // Move the scanner past the Unicode value
        [scanner scanString:code intoString:nil];
    }
}

NSLog(@"result=%@", result);
```

Comment: Looks promising, but I do not see how it will convert every type character, for example "in the cell&#039;s nucleus"

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [JSON Framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework), then all you do is get your JSON string and convert it to an `NSArray` like so:

```
NSString * aJSONString = ...;
NSArray * array = [aJSONString JSONValue];
```

The library is well-written, and will automatically handle UTF8 encoding, so you don't need to do anything beyond this.  I've used this library several times in apps that are on the store.  I *highly* recommend using this approach.

Comment: I am already doing this:

 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];

 NSString *jsonreturn = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url]; 
 
 NSDictionary *dict = [jsonreturn JSONValue];